# Not able to get data url when using images in kinetic js

Tags: javascript, kineticjs

I'm using kinetic js to build an application using HTML5 canvas where users drag and drop images and then save the final image. It is giving the following error:
**Unable to get data URL. SecurityError: DOM Exception 18** 
Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It happens when the images drawn onto the canvas and the code are on different server. As quoted from the http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/kineticjs/html5-canvas-stage-data-url-with-kineticjs/:

"**The toDataURL() method requires that any images drawn onto the canvas are hosted on a web server with the same domain as the code executing it.  If this condition is not met, a SECURITY_ERR exception is thrown**"